# Ошибка: TypeError: cartProducts.querySelector is not a function

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему выдает ошибку:
TypeError: cartProducts.querySelector is not a function ?

Вот код:

```
let cartProducts = objGod.id;
      console.log(cartProducts);
if (cartProducts) {
   let id = cartProducts.querySelector('.cart-product').dataset.id;
       console.log(id); 
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: судя по всему ты пытаешься вызвать `.querySelector` у строки.

Comment: а html разметки тут нет......как понять куда применяется этот код?

Comment: вот почему обращение к глобальным идентификаторам зло и неявная типизация и сранвнение тоже)) А вот была бы проверка явная, а не `if (cartProducts)` проблемы бы не было))